# How secure are shared tables in CloudKit?

Tags: security, cloudkit

Imagine we are building a shared bookmarking app with the following tables:

- Company (companyID)
- User (userID, companyID)
- Bookmark (bookmarkID, content, companyID)

A user should only be able to access the bookmarks which match their companyID.

Traditionally you would ensure this kind of security by not giving a client direct access to the database. Instead you would have a server that would authenticate the user, and the client would send a unique token to the server along with a request for Bookmarks. Once the server receives this token, it would know exactly which records in the Bookmarks table the user is allowed to access.

That's great, but what if you don't have a server, and you want to rely purely on CloudKit?

Since you don't have a server, it seems like you must allow full access to the Bookmarks table to each user. Then, the client side code would be responsible for preventing access to records that are off-limits. (E.g. When you send a retrieve Bookmark request, you would use a predicate such as `companyID == 3`.)

The question is how secure is a system like this which allows full access by the client, but limits it based solely on client side code?

(Note: For this question, assume an attacker jailbreaks their phone, and uses whatever means necessary to access data they aren't allowed to see. In the case where we were using a server, we don't care if they jailbreak their phone, since all requests still need to go through our servers. The only way they would be able to access data they can't see is if they found out the secret token that is assigned to another user. However, when the attacker has access to another user's phone, I'm assuming all bets are off: the attacker would be able to figure out the secret token that other client is using and then access that user's private data. Therefore, the original question I posed can ignore the case where the attacker has access to another person's phone, since even in the more secure version (with a server), all bets are off. In other words, assume the attacker has access to their own phone only for the following questions.)

Examples of things I am wondering:

- Can the attacker figure out which credentials the client is using for CloudKit and then run custom queries against CloudKit?
- Assuming I am using a predicate such as `@"companyID == %@"` and replacing the `%@` with the contents of a variable, can the attacker simply change the value of this variable before the query is sent?
- Assuming I am using a predicate of the form `@"companyID == 3"`, can the attacker simply change the string to `@"true || companyID == 3"` so that they get all records?
- Can the attacker monitor network traffic and see requests that are being sent to CloudKit and then modify those using a man-in-the-middle technique?
- Say I want to prevent duplicate companyIDs from being created so before I create a company, I run a query to fetch that companyID. Once I have the company stored in a local variable, I run code such as `if companyID != nil { return }` before I create the company. Can the attacker modify their client so that it doesn't execute this line of code? What if instead of `companyID != nil`, I use a boolean, `companyExists`. Would that make any difference?
- Before I send a new bookmark to CloudKit to be saved, I run code such as `bookmark[@"companyID"] = 3` to set the proper companyID. If the attacker changed this value to `4`, for example, it would be a security violation. Can they do something of this nature?
- Does the client matter? I'm primarily concerned with iOS, but what if I made an Android or JavaScript client? Would that make it any more/less secure?
- Does the OS version matter? Should I only users to run the app if they are on the latest OS for maximum security, or does that not matter?
- Are there any other things you can think of that would make this system less secure than the server based model? (I can think of at least one: If you had a bug in an old version of the app which printed the entire contents of a table, for example, there would be no easy way to correct this. A user could purposely avoid upgrading their app with the intent of stealing people's private data forever. The only way around this would be to migrate all the data to new tables that the old client doesn't know about. I'm sure this would be a pain.)